# Pulling, Storing & Destroying Files from an Amazon S3 Bucket w/ Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to pull a single PDF file from my Amazon S3 bucket. Then I want to convert it to OCR, and then clear the bucket. This is the code basic structure.

```rb
class SyncronizeBucketJob
  def perform
    s3_objects = get_s3_files
    create_ocr_documents(s3_objects)
    remove_s3_objects(s3_objects)
  end

  def get_s3_files
    # get list of s3 files here 
  end

  def create_ocr_documents(s3_objects)
    # for each s3 object create new OcrDocument with a file from s3
  end

  def remove_s3_objects(s3_objects)
  # physically go and delete each s3 file
  end   
end
```

After reading through the documentation many times I've gotten to here,

```rb
def perform
  s3_objects = get_s3_files
  create_ocr_documents(s3_objects)
  remove_s3_objects(s3_objects)
  @bucket = bucket
  @object_key = object_key
end

def pull_s3_files
  bucket = s3_resource.bucket('')
  bucket.objects.select do |obj|
    # return true if obj is pdf
end

def create_ocr_documents
  Courts::Utils::PdfVersionConverter.new(input_path: tmp_file_path, output_path: tmp_output_file_path).call
end

def remove_s3_objects
  # physically go and delete each s3 file
  object = s3_resource.bucket(bucket).object(object_key)
  object.delete
end
```

But it's still not functioning, being a novice with rails and even more with AWS I'm at a loss as to where to proceed.

Comment: Hi, sharing your code is good, but you also need to explain more about the problem you are having. You describe three steps, but which one is not working? Can you edit your question with any error messages in your logs?

Comment: Since you are new to both Rails and AWS, have you considered using [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)? It's standard Rails and, although it has its wrinkles, it might help you focus on what you're trying to do rather than dealing directly with buckets and such.

Comment: Might also take a look at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby. I think that, and/or the rails sdk gem, should get you to where you want to go. Also the aws ruby docs might help https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/